# Linq Join with XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have two xmls files and I want to make queries above them using Linq. I'm able to do simples queries with XDocument, but know I'm trying to build a join by an specific element, Ex: DE2002. These are examples of both xmls files. Any suggestion?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataBase>
  <Record RecordType="4">
    <DE1017>245254</DE1017>
    <DE1021>2435234525</DE1021>
    <DE2002>65456464</DE2002>
  </Record>
  <Record RecordType="4">
    <DE1017>245245</DE1017>
    <DE1021>24525442</DE1021>
    <DE2002>56464</DE2002>
  </Record>
</DataBase>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataBase>
  <Record RecordType="4">
    <DE1017>245245</DE1017>
    <DE1021>23434</DE1021>
    <DE2002>65456464</DE2002>
  </Record>
  <Record RecordType="4">
    <DE1017>23452345</DE1017>
    <DE1021>va2345234523lue2</DE1021>
    <DE2002>56464</DE2002>
  </Record>
</DataBase>
```

Comment: I think you'd want to first load the xml data into a list containing a class that well represents the data structure.  Then you'd be able to use linq to query against that list.  So, you could have a list of Records, where records have properties of Record Type,  DE1017, DE1021, DE2002 and etc.I'd recommend you give that a quick try, add the details/code of your attempt to your question, and then ask a more focused question.

Comment: These xml blobs are identical to each other, is the correct, or did you mean to post 2 different ones?

Answer (score 0):

You can join them like this:

```
XElement list1 =
new XElement("DataBase",
    new XElement("Record",
        new XAttribute("RecordType", "4"),
        new XElement("DE1017", "245254"),
        new XElement("DE1021", "2435234525"),
        new XElement("DE2002", "65456464")),
    new XElement("Record",
        new XAttribute("RecordType", "4"),
        new XElement("DE1017", "245245"),
        new XElement("DE1021", "24525442"),
        new XElement("DE2002", "56464")));

XElement list2 =
new XElement("DataBase",
    new XElement("Record",
        new XAttribute("RecordType", "4"),
        new XElement("DE1017", "245245"),
        new XElement("DE1021", "23434"),
        new XElement("DE2002", "65456464")),
    new XElement("Record",
        new XAttribute("RecordType", "4"),
        new XElement("DE1017", "23452345"),
        new XElement("DE1021", "24525va2345234523lue2442"),
        new XElement("DE2002", "56464")));

var query = list1.Descendants("Record").Join(list2.Descendants("Record"),
                                 o => o.Descendants("DE2002").First().Value,
                                 i => i.Descendants("DE2002").First().Value,
                                 (o, i) => new { List1 = o, List2 = i });
```

This joins them using the `Value` from the first `DE2002` element in each `Record`.  For every match, a new anonymous object is created with `List1` and `List2` properties, populated from the matching rows.

This would be significantly easier if you were to do this with "real" classes, populated from XML, instead of directly from the XML data source.

LINQPad file available [here](http://share.linqpad.net/famwt8.linq).

---

This gives 2 resulting "rows" that look like:

[image]